# XamarinMediaManager: Changing CurrentPosition of the MediaQueue in CrossMediaManager

Tags: xamarin

Im using XamarinMediaManager (https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager) in a Xamarin Forms App and want to set the CurrentPosition of my MediaQueue. So let's say I have a playlist with audio file A, B and C but instead of the starting with playing audio file A, I want to start with B. So I can execute previous and A will be played.

I did set the CurrentPosition of the MediaQueue (see option 1 and option 2) but both seems to have no effect or is reseted after the mediaplayer starts.

**Sample option 1**

```
var media = new[]{
pathA,
pathB,
pathC,
};

await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(media );
CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaQueue.CurrentIndex = 1;
```

**Sample option 2**

```
var extractor = CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaExtractor

CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaQueue.Add(await extractor.CreateMediaItem(pathA)); 
CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaQueue.Add(await extractor.CreateMediaItem(pathB));
CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaQueue.Add(await extractor.CreateMediaItem(pathC));

CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaQueue.CurrentIndex = 1;
```

//same code as in the existing play method

```
var mediamanager = CrossMediaManager.Current as MediaManagerImplementation;    mediamanager.MediaBrowserManager.MediaController.GetTransportControls().Prepare();
```

Comment: Changing the CurrentIndex in MediaQueue seems won't play corresponding audio here.I checked the demo and find set CurrentIndex is used to reset the index when you start to play from first item again.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation here:  https://github.com/Baseflow/XamarinMediaManager, you need to call:
`await CrossMediaManager.Current.PlayQueueItem(int index);`